# Possible to set homepage for Firefox Private window?

Tags: firefox, browser

Is it possible to set a default homepage for the Firefox private browsing window so that I don't have to see the default Private window page as attached.

[image]

Comment: Questions about Web browser functionality belong on [su].

Comment: This is [not currently implemented](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=860133)